# Can't change background color of the View if color defined in the XML

Tags: java, android, xml, colors

I came across strange issue. I have a RelativeLayout, I define the background color in the XML the following way:

```
 <RelativeLayout ..
      android:background="#449966">
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to programmatically update the background color, so I did this:

```
 view.setBackgroundColor( Color.argb( 255, 200, 150, 133 ) );
```

Which strangely works ONLY if I remove the *background* attribute from the XML file. If the *background* attribute is present, the background color does not change when set programmatically.

So since the *background* attribute seems to expect *Drawable*, I thought maybe I need to create a drawable as well and use *setBackground* method instead, so I did:

```
 Drawable newColor = new ColorDrawable( Color.argb( 255, 200, 150, 133 ) );
 view.setBackground( newColor );
```

But still the background color does not change, IF the *background* attribute is present in the XML. It seems like if the *background* attribute is defined in the XML, it cannot be "*overwritten*".

Any suggestions please? Thank you!

Comment: The only thing I can really think of that would cause the described behavior is that you're somehow ending up with overlapping `View`s, and your code is setting the background on one that's behind another. The `RelativeLayout` is transparent by default, so if that's the case, then setting the background on one "in the back" would not appear to work when you specify the color in the layout, but it would when you don't. In any case, we need more information to be certain of what the issue is.

Comment: I checked your problem, but it works for me. Can you share both your Activity and layout of it?

Answer (score 0):

that's because each view behaves differently than other,  and when you try to change the general view color which is the 'layout' view it will never work, so you should call the 'RelativeLayout' by id and then change its view :

```
 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/myview"
  android:background="#449966">
 </RelativeLayout>
```

in java :

```
 view.findViewById(R.id.myview).setBackgroundColor(Color.argb( 255, 200, 150, 133 ));
```